# M1 mbp use xcode 12.5.1 to debug with device "my mac(designed for iphone)", but "failed to launch or exited before the debugger could attach to it"

Tags: ios, apple-m1, apple-silicon

the complete message like

`“hellom1” failed to launch or exited before the debugger could attach to it. Please verify that “hellom1” has a valid code signature that permits it to be launched on “My Mac”. Refer to crash logs and system logs to for more diagnostic information.`

It's just a simple hello world app.

then I try to track the information in console.app.

here are the log, which I filter with my project name: "hellom1"

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xXmHtr200taTXVDDhpU7SlBYqZ3yKYYgVD6PehW4kt8/edit?usp=sharing

```
默认  23:00:03.387937+0800    appinstalld Failed to open macho file at /var/db/appinstalld/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.PRyEgA/extracted/hellom1.app/Executable for reading: No such file or directory
默认  23:00:03.387948+0800    appinstalld Failed to iterate macho file at /var/db/appinstalld/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.PRyEgA/extracted/hellom1.app/Executable
默认  23:00:03.395157+0800    appinstalld 0x16dc43000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:waitForDeletion:withError:]: Made container live for com.carusd.hellom1 at /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A0479CD2-1C09-4C11-A607-C64491791E11
默认  23:00:03.397789+0800    appinstalld com.carusd.hellom1:7:4:2:1:Success (End) : Install (Placeholder)
```

But I dont know why, dose anyone know how to fix it?